# MVC controller not called in Area

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a MVC controller that I don't get to work properly.

On a page, I have a form with an action link somewhere in that form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.ActionLink("Neues Gastkonto anlegen", "Index", "NewGuest", null, new { @class="button"})
            </th>
        </tr>
      ...
</table>
}
```

That link properly gets rendered as `<host>/GluexDB/NewGuest`. Note that I'm working in an area GluexDB and my routes are properly set up.

The NewGuestController is as follows:

```
public class NewGuestController : Controller
{
    IGluexDBServiceFactory serviceFactory;

    //used for injecting the database
    public NewGuestController(IGluexDBServiceFactory serviceFactory)
    {
        if (serviceFactory == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Please provide a valid serviceFactory");
        }

        this.serviceFactory = serviceFactory;
    }


    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("CnG Cont"); //<-- no exception thrown here
        return View("CreateNewGuest");
    }
```

However, clicking on the link in the first page doesn't throw an exception but tells me `The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations.` Even if no exception would be thrown, shouldn't the View searched for be named `CreateNewGuest`?

For completeness, this is the route configuration:

```
public class GluexDBAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
{
    public override string AreaName 
    {
        get 
        {
            return "GluexDB";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "GluexDB_default",
            "GluexDB/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add the route parameter for the area as follows:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Neues Gastkonto anlegen", "Index", "NewGuest", 
                        new { area = "GluexDB"}, new { @class="button"})
```

**[MSDN Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ee671793(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-9)**

**Update**

The solution was as below from @Thaoden's comments:

"Turns out, it was my code, in order to inject the serviceFactory, I had to overwrite `GetControllerInstance` of `DefaultControllerFactory`. I messed it up so that both `TutorController` (primary page) and `NewGuestController` returned an instance of `TutorController`, thus the `NewGuestController` would never be reached."

Comment: I changed it accordingly, but still the controller isn't called. The error message remains the same.

Comment: @Thaoden Are you calling the area registration in the global.asax? i.e. `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();`

Comment: Yes, there is `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()` in the Application_Start(). I'm currently working on an existing project with multiple existing areas, they all work.

Comment: @Thaoden I can't see anything obvious, it may be caching. You could try re-starting and putting a breakpoint in the RegisterArea to make sure it hits it.

Comment: I did a clean and a rebuild multiple times already. A breakpoint on the Index action doesn't get hit either.

Comment: @Thaoden Sorry to say this but I've tested the exact code with my addition in a new project and it works fine. Try it quickly in a new project with just registering that area and you will see. It must be something outside of what you have in the question.

Comment: @Thaoden No probs. Good luck. ps You do still need that `new { area = "GluexDB"}` mind. :)

Comment: Finally found it. Turns out, it was my code, in order to inject the serviceFactory, I had to overwrite `GetControllerInstance` of `DefaultControllerFactory`. I messed it up so that both `TutorController` (primary page) and `NewGuestController` returned an instance of `TutorController`, thus the `NewGuestController` would never be reached.

Comment: @Thaoden Nice one, I couldn't have determined that from the code above. I'll reference it in the answer. :)

Comment: Thanks. But the `Html.ActionLink` is working fine without the explicit mention of the area. I guess it's because I'm not changing the area but staying in the same. As I mentioned in the question, the link is rendered just fine :)

Comment: @Thaoden Oh right, thanks. I'll remove that part. It must be getting set somewhere else. Good luck with the rest. :)